# How to launch my own compiled app in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, qt, .desktop

I have compiled a GUI app using QT 5.11 in Ubuntu 18.04. The app works perfectly if launched from a terminal.
I cannot launch it by double clicking it in Nautilus (it says no app is installed for shared libray files, something close), and I found that this is a nice new "security improvement" of nautilus. Therefore I have created a .desktop file in my ~/.local/share/applications folder :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/eqe/Bureau/EQE/Qpl
Path=/home/eqe/Bureau/EQE/
Name=EQE & PL 7.0
GenericName=photolum and EQE
Icon=EQE
Terminal=false
```

The application shows up in the grid button but unfortunately it doesn't launch when I click it, nothing happens.

Any idea of how I could "graphically" start my app, instead of using the terminal - looks like a huge step back to me.

---

**Update:**
If I go in the directory where I put the executable application file with a terminal and I enter ./Qpl (Qpl being the name of the file), it works perfectly. My Qt application launches a window and perform perfectly until I close it.

If now, I open nautilus and double click the file I get a message "no application is installed to open shared library files" (translated from French).

Having created the desktop file listed above, nothing happens when I try to launch it from the "grid button" at the bottom left of the screen.

Comment: Try to enable the terminal for debugging. This would allow you to see if there is any output to stdout and stderr. When you are done, you can disable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Exec=` line from

```
Exec=/home/eqe/Bureau/EQE/Qpl
```

to

```
Exec=/bin/bash "/home/eqe/Bureau/EQE/Qpl"
```